# Transition for images in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

Can I apply transitions for images in my wp7 application? I have a set of images. Can I create transition for these images like page transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply transition on any ui element.

```
//XAML
 <Image Name="img"
                Source="image.JPG"></Image>

//C# put this code on any event like on a button click.

RotateTransition rotatetransition = new RotateTransition();
            rotatetransition.Mode = RotateTransitionMode.In180Counterclockwise;


            ITransition transition = rotatetransition.GetTransition(img);
            transition.Completed += delegate { transition.Stop(); };
            transition.Begin();
```

This will apply transition to an image